# How to update an entry on Elastic Search using Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to make an update on my es model information using an elastic search client

```
org.elasticsearch.client.Client
```

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.elasticsearch.client.Client

It is really hard for me to find the correct way to do it since I dont know the index and the matcher, Im sorry, I am very beginer at this subject.

```
  {
    "_index": "my_index_20",
    "_type": "student",
    "_id": "a80ae58",
    "_source": {
      "model": {
        "id": "a80ae58748e",
        "name": "John Doe"
        ....
```

My code so far

```
 response = esClient.prepareUpdate("student", "name", "John Doe")
                    .setDoc(jsonBuilder()               
                    .startObject()
                    .field("name", "Joe Doe")
                    .endObject())
                    .get();
```

Am I using the right index? or what could I change here?

I am not getting any error but a "document missing" result... means I might not be using the right indexes.

Ideas?

Updated according feedback and more info...

I moved it to

```
response = esClient.prepareUpdate("my_index_20", "student", "a80ae58")
                    .setDoc(jsonBuilder()               
                    .startObject()
                    .field("name", "Joe Doe")
                    .endObject())
                    .get();
```

This works but since I dont know the index ID I cannot perform this, is there any way to do it by a query builder or other functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This is the signature of the **prepareUpdate** method:

```
UpdateRequestBuilder prepareUpdate(String index, String type, String id);
```

So the correct syntax may be

```
esClient.prepareUpdate("my_index_20", "student", "a80ae58").setDoc(...)...
```

If you want to do it by matching other field, use the update by query.

```
String indexName = "my_index_*"; //Assuming that you don't know the exact index, but know the global format (for example the beginning of the name of the index)
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "John Doe"));
boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("otherField", "otherFieldValue"));
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(esClient);
updateByQuery.source(indexName); 
updateByQuery.filter(boolQuery); 
BulkByScrollResponse updateResponse = updateByQuery.get();
```

Comment: Hi, yes, but I dont have the ID itself, is there anyway I can do it by matching other field?

Comment: of course. Use the update by query. See this link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html

Comment: any idea how to do it for this case? :s it still says I need indexes

Comment: If you don't kwon the exact index, but kwon the global format (for example the beginning of the name of the index), you can do some thing like this:

`String indexName = "my_index_*";
    
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "John Doe"));
    
    UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(esClient);
    updateByQuery.source(indexName);
    updateByQuery.filter(boolQuery);
    
    BulkByScrollResponse updateResponse = updateByQuery.get();
`

Comment: @user6441481 you should update your answer with that code, it'd be more legible

Comment: what dependency is required to use BulkByScrollResponse? and where actually you are sending the new value for the field? could you please explain?